# Integrate Visual Basic and PHP to upload an image?

Tags: php, vb.net

I recently have been getting a grasp of understanding how Visual Basic works. I decided I want to combine the skills I have learned in PHP & VB to create an application that works hand in hand. I found a PHP script that allows me to upload image files that is shown below:

upload.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["submit"])) {

    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png" && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2500000 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";

      }
      else {

        $fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $fname);

        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Stored in: " . $fname;

      }

    }
    else {

      echo "Invalid file type";

    }

}
```

It's a very simple image upload script. Now, I have an application I have developed in Visual Basic that contains the following:

https://i.gyazo.com/91e9f9723944ab57a1fe4a0adf3a7c6b.png

Now, I am confused on how to do this. Should I have it directly go to upload.php and send a request to upload the image? If so, how do I go about sending a request to the file and accepting my image as a file through Visual Basic?

Comment: VB.NET (and .NET in general) has nothing to do with PHP. The syntax might be somehow similar (mainly to the C# one rather than to the VB.NET one), but everything else is different; including what is required to execute the resulting applications (even within .NET there are different approaches, requiring different conditions; for example: desktop applications vs. web applications). Your question is only proving your absolute lack of knowledge about the situation you think that you can face (which you cannot)...

Comment: ... I recommend you to focus on learning something properly (PHP or .NET; one of its sub-categories, as far as .NET is really big), before thinking about moving to the next thing. Also I recommend you to start understanding concepts as "it is easy" within the right context; that is: what is easy for certain person (with certain knowledge, attitude, etc.) might be extremely difficult for other person. Additionally, when you need to take 1000 steps to reach a goal; reaching this goal might be easy if you follow the 1000 steps; but impossible if you want to do everything in just 1 step.

Comment: @varocarbas my question does show a lack of knowledge, that's why I came here to find a solution. Thanks for stating the obvious.

Comment: This is not the kind of lack of knowledge which is the necessary requisite to ask a specific question in SO (e.g., I don't know how to make this specific bit of code to behave in this way on account of...); but the one which is only a requisite to do some heavy learning (and/or hire someone else) before even trying to code anything. For example: a question like "what is the gas pedal" doesn't entitle you to drive a car after just asking some tiny bits, but to go directly to the driving school and learn a lot. If all this was obvious why are you here asking such a nonsense?